# How to stop Android Studio from indenting next line after single line comment

Tags: android-studio, settings, indentation, auto-indent

This is driving me nuts. I just want to write a series of // single line comments aligned on the same column but when I hit the enter key Android studio auto-indents and I get the following:

```
//Todo do need to determine next fragment to navigate to
    //
```

Instead of:

```
//Todo do need to determine next fragment to navigate to
//
```

It also injects a tab instead of spaces so that the backspace key brings me back to the end of the previous line.

I can't find anything in settings.
Thanks

Comment: Strange behaviour, I don't have it. Probably need to look in code tab. "code">"Auto-Indent lines" maybe?

Comment: I can't find any "Auto Indent lines" setting in android studio 4.0 Beta 5

Comment: It's working normally today and I haven't changed anything. I'll leave the question open for a few more days and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It's happening to me too and is annoying

Answer (score 0):

Seems the options are in:

File -> Settings -> CodeStyle -> C/C++ ->

Uncheck these options:

[ ] Use Tab Character

[ ] Keep Indents on Empty Lines

Then [Apply] then [OK]

In my case, I even have to Exit/Re-enter Android Studio, in order for the changes to take effect (I believe it's a bug).

And also, placing Settings, under File menu, is NOT quite trivial for me (at least in my other IDE apps).